# getting all possible combinations of a list in a form of sublists

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics, python-itertools

I wonder if someone can help with the following task: 
What is the way to get all combinations a list can be split into sublists, when order does not matter?

Let's say I have a list of 4 items:

```
import itertools as it

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(it.combinations(a, 2)))
```

That will give me a list of 6 possible pairs:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

How to make (out of it? or any other way) a set of lists that contain original `[1, 2, 3, 4]` sequence in any order? So for this example it will contain three sublists:

```
 [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
 [(1, 3), (2, 4)]
 [(1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

UPDATE:
A small clarification: 
In other words, I need to get all sets of n-tuples such that their members contain all the population of original list, when the order within an n-tuple does not matter. Thus `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]` is ok, but `[(2, 1), (3, 4)]` is not needed because it is the same as the first set, if we ignore the order.

UPDATE2:
So for the list of length 6, and for chunks of size 2 this `fun` function should work as follows:

```
import itertools as it
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,]
r = 2

# fun(a,r):
# OUT:
# [
#    (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
#    (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6),
#    (1, 4), (2, 3), (5, 6),
#    (1, 5), (2, 3), (4, 6),
#    (1, 6), (2, 3), (4, 5),
#  ]
```

Comment: Did you try `print(list(it.permutations(a, 4)))`? Might that be what you're looking for?

Comment: The last part of your question doesn't agree with your desired output. You say _"...that contain original `[1, 2, 3, 4]` sequence in any order?"_ For that you would simply reshuffle using something like `random.shuffle`. What your output is telling me is that you want to randomly pick pairs from `list(it.combinations(a, 2))`. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: @JosephWood: Sure, let me clarify a bit: I need to get all sets of n-tuples such that their members contain all the population of original list, when the order within an n-tuple does not matter. Thus `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]` is ok, but `[(2, 1), (3, 4)]` is not needed because it is the same as the first set, if we ignore the order

Answer (score 2):

Just `zip` the combinations, with its reverse and take only the first half of the resulting list

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> r = len(lst)//2
>>> combs = list(it.combinations(lst, r))
>>> list(it.islice(zip(combs, reversed(combs)), len(combs)//2))
[((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 3), (2, 4)), ((1, 4), (2, 3))]
```

Comment: This solution works for this specific list length. For `lst = list(range(1,7))` it splits it into subgroups of 3: `[((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)), ((1, 2, 4), (3, 5, 6)), ((1, 2, 5), (3, 4, 6)), ((1, 2, 6), (3, 4, 5)), ((1, 3, 4), (2, 5, 6)), ((1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)), ((1, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5)), ((1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 6)), ((1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5)), ((1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4))]
`

Comment: and with `lst = list(range(1,7))` and `r = 2` it produces the wrong result: `[((1, 2), (5, 6)), ((1, 3), (4, 6)), ((1, 4), (4, 5)), ((1, 5), (3, 6)), ((1, 6), (3, 5)), ((2, 3), (3, 4)), ((2, 4), (2, 6))]`

Comment: It works only when r is `len(lst)/2`. Can you give an example output you expect when `r=2` for a list for length 7

Comment: Just added an example in UPDATE2 in the main text

Answer (score 0):

As you require the "remainder" of what is in `a`, you can use a `set` difference

```
In [901]: [(c, tuple(set(a) - set(c))) for c in it.combinations(a, 2)]
Out[901]:
[((1, 2), (3, 4)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 4)),
 ((1, 4), (2, 3)),
 ((2, 3), (1, 4)),
 ((2, 4), (1, 3)),
 ((3, 4), (1, 2))]
```

However, this gives you twice as many results as you require so to eliminate these duplicates we need to sort and `set`ify the result set which will give us a set of `list`s which can't be turned into `set`s. You should then cast the `list`s to `tuple`s.

```
In [900]: {tuple(sorted((c, tuple(set(a) - set(c))))) for c in it.combinations(a, 2)}
Out[900]: {((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 3), (2, 4)), ((1, 4), (2, 3))}
```

If you require a `list` of `list` of `tuple` then you can use the following

```
In [902]: s = {tuple(sorted((c, tuple(set_a - set(c))))) for c in it.combinations(a, 2)}

In [903]: [list(l) for l in s]
Out[903]: [[(1, 3), (2, 4)], [(1, 4), (2, 3)], [(1, 2), (3, 4)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
choices = []
for i in range(len(a)):
  for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
      sub_a1 = (a[i], a[j])
      sub_a2 = tuple(j for j in a if j not in sub_a1)
      sub_a = sorted([sub_a1, sub_a2])
      if sub_a not in choices:
         choices.append(sub_a)
for k in choices:
  print(k)
```

May be this code can help your requirements.