# Python combine every entry of the first list with every entry of the second

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I want to put a 2 dimensional list into a function so that it returns a two dimensional list with every of the second list entry combined, like this:

```py
List2D = [['a','b','c'], [1, 2, 3]]

def MyFunction(List2D):
    ...
    (some code here)
    ...
    print(TheFinalList)
```

> desired output: [['a1','a2','a3'], ['b1','b2','b3'], ['c1','c2','c3']]

Comment: why are you using `exec` here? In any case, your desired output doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting all possible combinations of a list in a form of sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915852/getting-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-in-a-form-of-sublists)

Comment: I agree with the other commenters, this is unclear at best. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: What does it mean to "combine" them? How do you combine the variable `a` with the value `1` to produce `a1`? Are they strings and you want to concatenate them?

Comment: i was using exec because i tought i had to create just a given amount of variables, relative to the size of the nested list.
But it was cunfusing code so i decided to remove it. It wouldnt help answering my question anyways.

Comment: @Inside_A_Matrix_Inside_A_Matri Even if you "need" a variable amount of variables, `eval()` is rarely the right choice.

Comment: So, are `a`, `b`, `c`, `a1`, `a2` etc. variables or are they supposed to be strings? If they are variables, what values are `a1`, `a2` etc. supposed to contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone deleted his post with the correct answer:

```
NewList2D = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]]

List = [[str(x)+str(y) for y in NewList2D[1]] for x in NewList2D[0]]
print(List)

output: [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]
```

credits to -Nick

Comment: That was me.My answer was based on my interpretation of what your question actually was and someone else downvoted it based on their interpretation and since downvotes rarely get reversed I've left it deleted.

Comment: I dont know much about stackoverflow, but you may post it again so i will click the accept button

Comment: I can't do that because it would be a duplicate answer. It's OK, just accept your own answer once the timer allows you to.

Comment: i believe my question was described very bad, so i feel sorry now. Just like my programming code is way too complex but works anyways, my questions seem to have the same effect. jesus i learned a lot in 10 minutes.

Comment: Don't worry about it. The important thing is you have an answer to your question.